# homeslider.owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, owl-carousel

Добрый день дорогие друзья ,проблема заключается в том что при использовании OwlCarousel в wordpress-е вот такая ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: homeslider.owlCarousel is not a function
at (index):449
at dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
at r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
```

не понимаю в чем проблема ,читал что возможно проблема в $ и нужно использовать jQuery но это не то.Скрипты так же подключены в правильном порядке

Comment: как вы подключаете скрипт для owl-карусели?

Comment: @Max wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.2.1', true );

Comment: you main script need include after owl script

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду jQuery подключить после owl скрипта?

Comment: No, your script that invokes owl

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не решили свою задачу, то предлагаю для начала отделить мух от котлет:
wp написан преимущественно на php и выполняется на сервер (хостинге)
owl-карусель на js и выполняеся на компьютере посетителя - это важно.
То есть,если у вас не находится функция в JS, то значит на странице у посетителя нет определения данной функции, а так как эта функция описана в скрипте, то значит нет скрипта.

Попробуйте на странице в браузере нажать CTRL+U и в открывшейся вкладке с кодом страницы визуально или с помощью CTRL+F найти место подключения скрипта с требуемой функцией. И место подключения скрипта с jQuery. Если таковых не будет, то значит подключаете не так и не там. Причём не важно, правитили вы header.php напрямую или используете function.php. Результирующий HTML код - код вашей страницы должен соответствовать канонам HTML и содержать требуемые строки.

Если строки есть, то убедитесь, что адрес правильный - может быть в строке подключения используется не тот, где фактически лежит скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему: подключил страницу в header-е страницы изменив параметр `false` на `true` в функции `wp_enqueue_script()`.